# Showing that composition can be represented by a map

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove proposition 5.6 in Lawvere and Rosebrugh.

The proposition goes like this.

Suppose $g:B \to Y_1$ and $\phi: Y_1 \to Y_2$ are arbitrary.

There exists a $\ulcorner c \urcorner: Y_2^{Y_1} \times Y_1^B \rightarrow Y_2^B$, such that $\ulcorner c\urcorner (\ulcorner \phi \urcorner,\ulcorner g \urcorner) = \ulcorner \phi g \urcorner$.

Now to start define $c: Y_2^{Y_1} \times Y_1^B \times B \to Y_2^B$ as the composite of $1 \times \text{eval}_1: Y_2^{Y_1} \times Y_1^B \times B \to Y_2^{Y_1} \times Y_1$ and $\text{eval}_2: Y_2^{Y_1} \times Y_1 \to Y_2$, where $1: Y_2^{Y_1} \rightarrow Y_2^{Y_1}$ is the identity. Then I wan't to invoke the universal property of one of the exponentials, in order to get $\ulcorner c \urcorner$ and then prove the equality in question, but I can't find the right one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know the book and since I can only guess what the notation is supposed to mean, I'll assume that this takes place in a cartesian closed category with terminal object $1$. If I interpret the question correctly, what we're trying to prove is the existence of the so-called *internal composition*. That is, the morphism $c\colon Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\to Y_2^{B}$ which makes the diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\times B @>{c\times \mathrm{id}_B}>> Y_2^{B}\times B\\
@V{\mathrm{id}\times\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1}}VV @VV{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_2}}V \\
Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1 @>{\mathrm{ev}_{Y_1,Y_2}}>> Y_2
\end{CD}$$
commute.

Since the adjunction map $\mathrm{hom}(Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B},Y_2^{B})\to \mathrm{hom}(Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\times B,Y_2)$ maps an arbitrary morphism $f\colon Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\to Y_2^{B}$ to the composition
$$Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\times B\xrightarrow{f\times\mathrm{id}_B}Y_2^{B}\times B\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_2}}Y_2,$$
we see that $c$ is just the unique element corresponding to $\mathrm{ev}_{Y_1,Y_2}\circ(\mathrm{id}_{Y_2^{Y_1}}\times\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1})$.

Finally, precompose the diagram with $1\times 1\times B\xrightarrow{([\phi],[g])\times\mathrm{id}_B}Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^B\times B$ and combine all the present adjunctions to conclude that $c([\phi],[g]) = [\phi\circ g]$.

**Addendum:** After having a look at the book in question and reading the question again, I realised that the above is not much more than the OP already knew. Here we go again, but using different words.

The universal (*exponential*) property of $Y^B\times B\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y}}Y$ is this: For every $X$ and each map $f\colon X\times B\to Y$ there exists a unique $[f]\colon X\to Y^B$ such that the composition
$$X\times B\xrightarrow{[f]\times\mathrm{id}_B}Y^B\times B\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y}}Y$$
equals $f$.
I'd rather conflict with the OP's notation than with mine above. Therefore, we define $f := \mathrm{ev}_{Y_1,Y_2}\circ(\mathrm{id}_{Y_2^{Y_1}}\times\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1})\colon Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\times B\to Y_2$ and from the exponential property (where $X = Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}$ and $Y = Y_2$) we get $c := [f]$, the unique map $c\colon Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\to Y_2^{B}$ making the above square diagram commute.

It remains to show that $c([h],[g]) = [h\circ g]$ for every pair of maps $g\colon B\to Y_1$ and $h\colon Y_1\to Y_2$ where $[g]\colon 1\to Y_1^B$ and $[h]\colon 1\to Y_2^{Y_1}$ are the unique maps such that
$$B \xrightarrow{[g]\times \mathrm{id}_B}Y_1^B\times B\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1}}Y_1$$
equals $g$ and
$${Y_1} \xrightarrow{[h]\times\mathrm{id}_{Y_1}} Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{{Y_1},Y_2}}Y_2$$
equals $h$. Thus, $h\circ g\colon B\to Y_2$ equals
$$
B\to 1\times 1\times B
\xrightarrow{1\times [g]\times \mathrm{id}_B}1\times Y_1^B\times B
\xrightarrow{1\times \mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1}}1\times Y_1
\xrightarrow{[h]\times \mathrm{id}_{Y_1}}Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{{Y_1},Y_2}}Y_2
$$
and substituting identities gives
\begin{align*}
h\circ g &= (B\to  1\times 1\times B
\xrightarrow{[h]\times [g]\times \mathrm{id}_B}Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^B\times B
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}_{Y_2^{Y_1}}\times \mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1}}Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{{Y_1},Y_2}}Y_2)
\\&=
(B\to  1\times 1\times B
\xrightarrow{[h]\times [g]\times \mathrm{id}_B}Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^B\times B
\xrightarrow{c\times\mathrm{id}_B}Y_2^{B}\times B
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_2}}Y_2)
\\&=
(B\to 1\times B
\xrightarrow{c([h]\times [g])\times \mathrm{id}_B}Y_2^{B}\times B
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_2}}Y_2).
\end{align*}
But this implies $c([h], [g]) = [h\circ g]$.

Comment: By the $\ulcorner g \urcorner$ for a morphism $g$ is just mean it's exponential transpose. I am not entirely comfortable with adjunctions yet, so, I am a little weary in using it. Is it possible to prove purely equationally, by using the fact that $\ulcorner g \urcorner$ has the exponential property uniquely? Many thanks!

Comment: Let me first get straight what the *exponential property* says; is it this: given $g\colon B\to Y_1$ there is a unique $[g]\in \mathrm{hom}(1,Y_1^B)$ such that the composition $$B \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}_B\times 1} B\times 1 \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}_B\times [g]}B\times Y_1^B\xrightarrow{\mathrm{ev}}Y_1$$ equals $g$? Note that this defines a bijection $\mathrm{hom}(B,Y_1)\to \mathrm{hom}(1,Y_1^B)$. Do you also have an exponential property at hand which says that there is a similar bijection $\mathrm{hom}(Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\times B,Y_2)\to \mathrm{hom}(Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B},Y_2^{B})$?

Comment: I have at hand, the general universal property of exponentials, since I am in the category of sets, and have this as an axiom, so I can do all that, yes.

Comment: I had a look at this book. You can replace each of my 'adjunction's by 'exponential property'. Take $f := \mathrm{ev}_{Y_1,Y_2}\circ(\mathrm{id}_{Y_2^{Y_1}}\times\mathrm{ev}_{B,Y_1})\colon Y_2^{Y_1}\times Y_1^{B}\times B\to Y_2$ and use the exponential property to get $\ulcorner f \urcorner$ such that $\mathrm{ev}(\ulcorner f \urcorner\times\mathrm{id}_B) = f$. This $\ulcorner f\urcorner$ is my $c$ above.

Comment: Okay, so if I do the last composition you mention, i get $ ([c] \times 1_B)( ([\phi],[g]) \times 1_B ) = [c]([\phi],[g])\times 1_B$ using the functoriality of products. But when I do the other side of the equation, I get $(id \times eval) (([\phi],[g]) \times 1_B)  = (id ([\phi],[g])) \times (eval 1_B)$ again by product functoriality, but that last bit seem to not make any sense to me, since $eval 1_B$ is not even defined?

Comment: Dear @Bartuc, I added the details.

Comment: Thank you very much! One last question, the $B \to 1 \times 1 \times B$ is that the unique arrow to from $B$ into $1$ or what?

Comment: You're welcome. The map is $1\times 1\times \mathrm{id}_B$; abstractly, it's the inverse to the projection map $1\times 1\times B\to B$.

Comment: Ah yes thank you!

Comment: Actually, why is it even needed? The morphisms for $h$ and $g$ already compose as is?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why is what even needed?

Comment: That is, why, for the composite $h \circ g$, do I have to compose the expressions for $h$ and $g$ via the evaluation maps with the map $B \to 1 \times 1 \times B$?, since the codomain of the expression for $g$ coincides with the domain for $h$?

Comment: Still, I'm not sure I understand. The ones can be dropped from the notation but this has nothing to do with the composability of $g$ and $h$. I put them there so that it is easier to see that the manipulations of the compositions are valid. If that's obvious for you then go ahead and ignore the map $B\to 1\times 1\times B$.

Comment: Ah, I see now, it makes sense to me now. Many Thanks!